# iOS Attempted to dereference garbage pointer

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, grand-central-dispatch

I am getting iOS crash report from Bugnag:

> Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x8000000000000010

Below is the class which I have in my project

```
class Presence {
    private var userStates = [Int: [String: Any]]()

   internal func saveState(state: UserPresenceState, updateTime: Date, for userId: Int) {
        let value = ["state": state, "updated_at": updateTime]
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "mySerialQueue")
        queue.sync { 
             self.userStates[userId] = value
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Attempted to dereference garbage pointer at line `self.userStates[userId] = value`. Not sure while accessing self or while accessing userStates variable

I am not sure why this is happening and unable to replicate it, how to solve these kinds of problems?

Is there anything know whether a variable is deallocated or not?

Any help much appreciated

FYI
I got the same error from bugsnag with below code too

```
internal func saveState(state: UserPresenceState, updateTime: Date, for userId: Int) {
    let value: [String: Any] = ["state": state, "updated_at": updateTime]
    self.userStates[userId] = value
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want `let queue` as a class property, and not as a local variable?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Thanks for looking into my issue, will it make any difference?

Comment: @harishkandikatla by defining your queue inside your method, it becomes useless. And the swift runtime may deallocate it before the end of the method.

Comment: @YannickLoriot `DispatchQueue` is not deallocated until all dispatched blocks finish, even if there are no stron reference to the queue

Comment: @harishkandikatla What you're doing is trying to allocate new `DispatchQueue`  in each call of your function, while using the same parameter each time. The queue is deallocated after dispatched block finishes, but it's unclear what would happen if you attempted to create a new one while a previous one, with the same label, still existed - the documentation for `DispatchQueue` constructor is non-existent

Comment: @harishkandikatla You should follow Milan's advice and make the queue a class property - `DispatchQueue` is a thread-safe class, so you don't have to worry about trying to call `queue.sync` from different threads

Comment: @mag_zbc @ Milan Nosáľ, @ mag_zbc
but I got the same error report from bugsnag before writing the queue